# PowerBI Custom column fiscal year

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am new with Power Bi. I want to add a custom column for Fiscal years with the help of order date. Here is my formula.Fiscal `Year=Number.RoundDown((12*Date.Year([Order Date]) + Date.Month([Order Date]) + 12- YearOfEnd)/12,0)` What is wrong as `YearOfEnd` function is not recognized?

Comment: Where did you get "YearOfEnd" ? If it is variable, how it is calculated?

Answer (score -1):

I did a search and found the below link:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Adding-a-column-to-show-Fiscal-Year/td-p/581875